# Incremental Learning in Text Classification: Handling the Addition of New Classes Without Retraining the Entire Model

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I am very new to ML learning. I tried searching but need directions from SEMs here.

Incremental Learning - How to handle the addition of new classes in text classification without retraining the entire model?

For example, suppose we initially have supervised 200 text emails for 3 users: User 1, User 2, and User 3. We have trained a classification model based on these 3 users as labels. With this model, we can predict the labels for new text samples within these 3 classes.

However, what if a new user, User 4, is added in the future? Can we incorporate the new user and their 15 emails into the existing model without retraining the entire model?

The goal is to achieve incremental learning, allowing the model to adapt to new classes as they are introduced, rather than starting from scratch.

Is there a way to update the existing model to accommodate the new user and their emails while retaining the knowledge learned from the previous classes? Can we perform incremental learning instead of retraining the entire model?

The objective is to find a method or approach that enables the seamless integration of new classes in a text classification model, facilitating the continued growth of the model as new users or classes emerge in the future.